# Upserting an elasticsearch document

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Here is the code I used. DocumentModel class is used as elasticsearch docment. Currently I am using url as elasticsearch '_id' ,and generating UUID for other field documentId using java. When I try to index a document using this code ,it updates document if exist,or index if not exist. Problem is when it updates document,it also updates documentId. But I require not to update documentId and use existing documentId.
what change should I made in this code to do so?

```
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                        documentModel.setDocumentID(uuid);
                        String jsonForIndex = gson.toJson(documentModel);
                        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indexName, typeName, documentModel.getId());
                        indexRequest.source(jsonForIndex);
                        UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(indexName, typeName, documentModel.getId());
                        updateRequest.doc(jsonForUpdate);
                        updateRequest.upsert(indexRequest);
                        UpdateQuery updateQuery = new UpdateQueryBuilder().withIndexName(indexName).withType(typeName)
                                .withId(documentModel.getId()).withDoUpsert(true).withUpdateRequest(updateRequest).withIndexRequest(indexRequest).build();
elasticsearchTemplate.update(updateQuery).getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform this as an elasticsearch atomic operation, you can use ES script to process the documentId field and keep the already existing one.

But if you want to use Java instead, you can perform a get, create the new one using the document id if exists and index only if there is no version change.

Something like (pseudo code):

```
old = client.prepareGet(indexName, type, uuid).get();

client.prepareIndex(indexName, type, uuid).setSource(<or the way you build it>).setVersion(old.getVersion() <if old is not null>).setRefresh(true).get();
```

If a concurrent transaction modified the document you were trying to update, it will throw a VersionConflictEngineException. You can use Spring Retry with this exception and do the get/index again (of let if fail if it is the desired behaviour).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to do that using UpdateQuery using IndexRequest and UpdateRequest(without using prepareGet)?